# What does offer/peek/poll in Java PriorityQueue translate to Python?

Tags: java, python

I am trying to reimplement Java's PQ in Python data structure, but looks like Java's PQ have some interesting methods:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

- `offer(E e)`
  Inserts the specified element into this priority queue.
- `peek()`
  Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.
- `poll()`
  Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

What does this translate to in Python's PQ? I don't see these methods in Python's version: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue

- `get()` Remove and return an item from the queue.
- `put()` Put item into the queue.

If my understanding is correct:
- poll() == get()

But wasn't sure whether offer() is the same as `put()`. And how we have to re-implement `peek()` ?

Comment: Poll() is a safe remove(). Poll() returns null if there is no item, remove() throws an exception. Likewise, offer() is a safe add(); offer() returns false if it can't put an element in the queue, put() throws an exception.

Comment: The methods you're asking about are from the Queue interface. PriorityQueue is just one implementing class.

Comment: Thanks, so it's really just same as `get()` and `put()` in Python, but a thread-safe version?

Comment: I don't use Python. Sorry. And no, they aren't thread-safe. Offer and poll don't throw exceptions, whereas add and remove can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `queue` module is specifically designed for inter-thread communication. Its design is not intended to facilitate single-threaded usage; for example, methods like `peek` don't make much sense for a thread synchronization mechanism, so `queue.PriorityQueue` doesn't have `peek` support. This is similar to how Go channels have no peek mechanism.

If you want a priority queue for reasons other than inter-thread communication, the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module is more appropriate. With `heapq`, `peek` is just `heap[0]`.

Comment: Great! Thanks!.

What's the big difference between `heappushpop()` vs `heappush()` ?

https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html

Comment: why doesn't it make sense to add a peek that is thread safe in queue ? I'm not sure i follow you on that.

Comment: @xbeta: `heappushpop` does a push and then a pop (but more efficiently than two separate calls), while `heappush` just does a push. This is pretty clearly explained in the docs.

Comment: In Java, the PrioityQueue is not thread-safe. PrioityQueue's have applictions outside of threads. It could be used in a thread-safe way, but this would require a bit of work.

Comment: @AlbinPaul: It's a recipe for race conditions. The intended usage of these queues is that there are producers on one end stuffing messages into the queue, and consumers claiming messages on the other end, with each message going to exactly one consumer. `peek` isn't much use in a system like that, and it encourages buggy patterns where messages get processed by multiple consumers or no consumers.